# Is there any difference between 어/아/여도 '되다', '좋다', and '괜찮다' to ask permission?

Tags: word-choice

It seems that 되다, 좋다, and 괜찮다 can all be used to ask for permission, or whether something is advisable:

> 담배 피워도 **좋습니까**? May I smoke?
>
> 한국말로 물어도 **돼요**? May I ask in Korean?
>
> 음식이 매워도 **괜찮아요**? Is it okay if the food is spicy?

Is there any difference between the use of 되다, 촣다, and 괜찮다, or are they basically interchangeable in meaning and tone?

Also, I know about the use of 면 안*되다* to deny permission, but they all be used to deny permission or say that something is inadvisable? Can you say "담배 피워도 좋지 않습니다" or "음식이 매워면 괜찮지 않아요"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically, they are same in the way asking permission to do something.

However, the word "좋습니까?" and "괜찮아요?" are considered to be more polite than just "돼요?".

So, if you're willing to do something, you can use '돼요?'

When that something affects other person, it's better to use '좋습니까?' or '괜찮아요?' instead.